# opencv image window/imshow

Tags: c++, opencv

I am just starting to use the Open CV library and one of my first code is a simple negative transform function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void negative(Mat& input,Mat& output)
{
  int row = input.rows;
  int col = input.cols;
  int x,y;
  uchar *input_data=input.data;
  uchar *output_data= output.data;


  for( x=0;x<row;x++)
    for( y=0;y<col;y++)
      output_data[x*col+y]=255-input_data[x*col+y];

    cout<<x<<y;



}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  Mat output=image.clone();

  negative(image,output);

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", output );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

I have added the extra line to check if the entire image is processed. The problem i am facing with my output image is that negative transform is applied only to top half of the image.

Now what happens is that the values for x and y are displayed only after i press a key (i.e. once the image is shown)

My question is why is the window being called before the function is executed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem in your code is that you are reading in a color image but you try to process it as grayscale. Therefore the indices shift and what really happens is that you only process the first third of the image (because of the 3-channel format).

[See opencv imread manual](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)

> flags –
>   Specifies color type of the loaded image:
>   >0 the loaded image is forced to be a 3-channel color image
>   =0 the loaded image is forced to be grayscale

You've specified flags=1.

Here's a way of doing it:

```
Vec3b v(255, 255, 255);
for(int i=0;i<input.rows;i++) //search for edges
{
    for (int j=0 ;j<input.cols;j++)
    {
        output.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = v - input.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
    }
}
```

Note that here Vec3b is a 3-channel pixel value as opposed to uchar which is a 1-channel value.
For a more efficient implementation you can have a look at `Mat.ptr<Vec3b>(i)`.

EDIT: 
If you are processing lots of images, 
for a general iteration over the pixels the fastest way is:

```
Vec3b v(255, 255, 255); // or maybe Scalar v(255,255,255) Im not sure
for(int i=0;i<input.rows;i++) //search for edges
{
    Vec3b *p=input.ptr<Vec3b>(i);
    Vec3b *q=output.ptr<Vec3b>(i);
    for (int j=0 ;j<input.cols;j++)
    {
        q[j] = v - p[j];
    }
}
```

See "The OpenCV Tutorials" -- "The efficient way" section.

Comment: That's interesting... I answered to the other question because of the "my question is ..." part =). Anyway, you're right as well.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs, you are a life saver :) thanks a lot. the problem is am used to an earlier custom library written by my department (mainly for grayscale). i have also written other codes for averaging which also failed due to the same error thanks once again. I am unable to link you to the comment thanks nevertheless

Comment: @Whereismywall no problem. :) updated my answer with details for developing a library. now you'll be able to link too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write:

```
cout << x << y << endl;
```

The function is called before, but the output is not flushed directly, which results in your image appearing before the text is written. By adding an "endline", you force a flush. You could also use `flush(cout);` instead of adding and endline.

---

For the negative, you can use the OpenCV function [subtract()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=subtract#subtract) directly:

```
subtract(Scalar(255, 255, 255), input, output);
```

Comment: however can you check if not `subtract(Vec3b(255,255,255), input, output)` is the correct? Also I think in-place works too and it is more efficient. (output can be the same as input, it does not need to be cloned.)

Comment: My mistake: the scalar has to have as many channels as the image. I edited it. And output doesn't have to be cloned indeed. He just has to declare it actually.